# Зависимоть свойст компонента Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Добрый день. Есть такой экземпляр

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   title: 'Hello World!',
    link: 'http://google.com'
  },
  methods: {
   changeTitle: function(event) {
     this.title = event.target.value;
    },
    sayHello: function() {
     this.title = 'Andrey';
     return this.title;
    },
    link_method: function() {
     return this.link;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1 v-once>{{ title }}</h1>
   <p>{{ title }}</p>
  <input type="text" v-on:input="changeTitle">
  <p>{{ sayHello() }}</p>
  <a v-bind:href="link_method()">Google</a>
</div>
```

И если запустить код на выполнение и в поле ввода что-то написать, то ни чего не поменяется. Хотя метод changeTitle наоборот способствует тому, чтоб текст изменялся везде, где это нужно. Но...

Если в методе sayHello удалить строку this.title = 'Andrey'; - то все работает так, как и планировалось. Вопрос - почему так происходит?

У меня есть такое объяснение, что изменение данной this.title влияет на все моменты её упоминания и т.к. она была упомянута в методе, который её возвращает, то и соответственно он пускается на выполнение каждый раз когда происходит изменение this.title. - Такое может быть полным бредом, но пока это единственное разумное для меня объяснение данного поведения.

С кодом можно тут поиграться [клик](https://jsfiddle.net/Andrey_Zimin/w8wd1s1h/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К каждому экземпляру компонента приставлен связанный с ним экземпляр наблюдателя, который помечает все поля, затронутые при рендеринге компонента, как зависимости. В дальнейшем, когда вызывается сеттер поля, помеченного как зависимость, этот сеттер уведомляет наблюдателя, который в свою очередь инициирует повторный рендеринг компонента.

Это из оф.док-ции. Т.е. мое предположение было верным. При изменении свойств компонента - это циклически затрагивает все вещи связанные с этим компонентом.

Используем this.$set.title вместо this.title

Answer (score 0):

Вся беда в том что вы в методе `sayHello` пишите:

```
this.title = 'Andrey';
return this.title;
```

И потом вызываете его на странице, и каждый раз когда вы работаете с инпутом отрабатывает метод `sayHello` который перебивает значение.

И советую лучше инпут переделать на модель:

```
<input type="text" v-model="title">
```

И тогда метод `changeTitle` не нужен, `v-model` работает по таком же принципу.

Comment: Вот штука-то и в том, что хочется понять по какой причине он каждый раз отрабатывает? Ведь за изменение input отвечает совсем другой метод и данный ни как с ним не связан.

Comment: Каждый раз он отрабатывает потому что он выводится на странице и когда меняется атрибут `titile` этот метод тоже вызывается чтобы отобразится с новыми данными

Comment: По какой причине этот метод вызывается при изменении инпута, если за это отвечает совсем другой метод?

Ну т.е. не стоит полностью передавать и цитировать мой собственный ответ. Т.к. объяснение, что он вызывается по тому, что он отображается на странице - не объяснение. С таким же успехом можно написать, что он вызывается по тому, что он есть. 

Если моё умозаключение верно, то так и скажите что оно верно, а не перефразируйте его. Если же нет, то если знаете - дайте разумно-техническое объяснение данному поведению.